# Custom AUC in R with different thresholds and binary predictions

Tags: r, auc

I am looking to plot a FPR vs TPR point on an AUC graph for different thresholds.

For example, if `data$C2` is my data frame with the true response column (either 0 or 1), I want to make a vector with predicted values (0 or 1) when `data$C1` (a different measurement column) is above or below the specified threshold. Here is the function I've attempted with the ROCR package.

```
 fun <- function (data, col1, col2){

   perfc <- NULL    #Create null vectors for prediction and performance
   perfs <- NULL
   temp <- NULL

 d <- seq(0.10,0.30,0.01)    ##Various thresholds to be tested

  for (i in length(d){

   temp <- ifelse(data[,col1] > d, 1 , 0)  ##Create predicted responses 
   pred <- prediction(temp, data[,col2])  #Predict responses over true values
   perf <- performance(pred, "tpr","fpr") #Store performance information

    predc[i] <- pred #Do this i times for every d in the sequence
    perfc[i] <- perf

   preds <- prediction.class(predc, col2)  #Combine to make prediction class
   perfs <- performance.class(preds, "tpr","fpr") #Combine to make performance class
}

  plot(perfs) #Plot TPR against FPR 
}
```

Is the problem because `temp` is a list vector and the true labels are from a matrix? Am I applying this for loop incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here's my attempt to do this manually without the ROC package.

```
for(t in seq(0.40,0.60,0.01))  #I want to do this for every t in the sequence
{
  t <- t
  TP <- 0
  FP <- 0
  p <- sum(data$C2==1, na.rm=TRUE)  #Total number of true positives
  n <- sum(data$C2==0, na.rm=TRUE)   #Total number of true negatives
  list <- data$C1 #Column to vector 
  test <- ifelse(list > t, 1, 0)  #Make prediction vector

 for(i in 1:nrow(data))
    {if(test==1 & data$C2==1)
      {TP <- TP + 1}  #Count number of correct predictions
   if(test==1 & data$C2==0) 
      {FP <- FP + 1}   #Count number of false positives
     }
  plot(x=(FP/n),y=(TP/p))    #Plot every FP,TP pair
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question right, but I think that by AUC graph you mean ROC curve. The ROC curve already takes into account different thresholds to make those classification decisions. See this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic). I found [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#/media/File:Receiver_Operating_Characteristic.png) particularly helpful.

If the above is right, then all you need to do in your code is:

```
pred <- prediction(data[,col1], data[,col2])  
perf <- performance(pred, "tpr","fpr")  
plot(perf)
```

If you would like to 'add' a different curve to that plot, perhaps because you used a different classification technique (e.g. decision tree instead of logistic regression. Then use `plot(perf2,add=TRUE)`. Where `perf2` is created in a same way as `perf`. See the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROCR/ROCR.pdf).

Comment: Is there anyway to restrict or input the specific thresholds I want to include in the ROC curve? Say t= 0.1 to t=0.3 and see the resulting tpr, fpr, accuracy, etc for each t?

Comment: How about the graph in this [gallery](http://rocr.bioinf.mpi-sb.mpg.de/rocr_gallery.html)?